# How to keep property value of object?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

This question belongs to fabricJS and canvas. I have define a property named `background` and initially it set as a false. I need to change object's property state as a true when user add a object to a canvas.

I have tried using `background = true;` but it change property value in whole canvas. How I do this for particular object when it add to the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want objects to have a background property, you need to equip the fabric.js Object type with a `background` property, by adding that to the prototype.

`fabric.Object.prototype.background = false;`

Later when you add an object, you can select your target object and assing

`myObject.background = true`

If you need to alter the object that is being added, you can listen to the `object:added` global listener on the canvas, like this:

```
myCanvas.on( 'object:added', function( e ) {
        var object = e.target;
        object.background = true;
} );
```

If you use object serialization somewhere in your code, you might need to modify the fabricjs-provided object serialization method to include your newly added `background` property.

```
fabric.Object.prototype.toObject = ( function ( toObject ) {
    return function () {
        return fabric.util.object.extend( toObject.call( this ), {
            background: this.background
        } );
    };
} )( fabric.Object.prototype.toObject );
```

Comment: that's correct. you may be shorter on toObject passing the property background as second parameter  standardObject.toObject(['background','othercustomprop...'])